# Maven Java Fx example does not run - not duplicate

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

Note: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) doesn't solve my problem, I compile AND run with same version.

I wanted to create maven Java FX project. I have followed this https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven Even if I take their example https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven and open it in Idea and try to run it, I get

```
    Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\force\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\13\javafx-base-13-win.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Unsupported major.minor version 55.0
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
```

The command running is

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\me\Development\Java\fxtest "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52546:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.3.2 clean org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run
```

What is wrong? Why can't I run this simple example project?

Comment: Maybe your Java is just in a directory called 13.0.2, but is a different version? Have you tried `java -version` and looked at the output?

Comment: Java -version shows 13.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable correct?

For me it's working when I run the project with `mvn clean javafx:run` in eclipse.

Comment: Actually, I have different version in JAVA_HOME, but the whole command should be starting with java 13 - please see the command above :)
Ok I tried to change JAVA_HOME and it works now. How it is possible that even after running it specifically with java 13 it still runs with java from JAVA_HOME? Do plugins run on different java version than maven?